# React-hot-reload with typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, ts-loader

I'm trying to add hot-reload with typescript on a codebase that is 90% `tsx`. For that, i'm following https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/tree/master/examples/react-hot-boilerplate.

I've added

```
 use: [
          { loader: 'ts-loader', options: { happyPackMode: true } }
],
```

So i started to get weird compilation errors:

> ERROR in ./client/main.tsx // <-- my entrypoint
>
> Module build failed
>   (from ./node_modules/ts-loader/index.js): TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'getEmitOutput' of undefined
>       at Object.getEmitOutput (....../node_modules/ts-loader/dist/instances.js:190:41)

No idea why... On my dependency tree, there are tsx, ts and also js files. Without these options, ts-loader compiles successfully.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true,
        "checkJs": false,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "jsx": "react",
        "lib": [
            "es2015",
            "es2016",
            "es2017",
            "dom",
            "es7"
        ],
        "downlevelIteration": true,
        "typeRoots": [
            "./@types"
        ],
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true
    },
    "include": [
        "./client/**/*",
        "./@types/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        ".svn"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please provide your Webpack config file.

Comment: whatelse do you need on my webpack config? there is already the needed piece (i.e: ts loader) there.

Comment: Make a minimal test case and file an issue against ts-loader?

Comment: i'll do that as soon as possible

Comment: @PlayMa256 How did you resolve the issue?